# Conditional independence for multiple variables

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Say we have a situation where A depends on B, and B depends on C. If I'm not mistaken, this means that A is independent of C given B (even though B depends on C, A given B sort of indirectly incorporates that already- that's how I understand it)

And we have the probability functions for

P(A|B) and P(B|C) and P(A,B|C)

There should be a way to get P(A|C) directly. My first guess is that P(A,B|C) can be changed into P(A|C), but I'm not sure how.

It makes sense intuitively since we have a chain of dependence, but I don't know where to start with the math. I tried using the chain rule and rearranging

$$P(A,B|C) = \frac{P(C|A,B)P(A|B)P(B)}{P(C)}$$

But I'm not sure how to rearrange that further

Comment: Your argument about the conditional independence of A and C does not convince me. It seems that all what you know is that $P(A \cap B) \neq P(A)P(B)$ and $P(B \cap C) \neq P(B)P(C)$. I do not see how can you conclude that $P(A \cap C \mid B) = P(A \mid B)P(C \mid B)$ using probability axioms. what do you mean by "get $P(A\mid C)$ directly"? Do you mean in terms only of $P(A \mid B)$, $P(B \mid C)$ and $P(A \cap B \mid C)$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by P(A|C). Sorry for the confusion. What I was trying to convey was a case where A only depends on B. But B in turn depends on C. And we're also given P(A,B|C). Supposedly that's enough to get an equation for P(A|C) in terms of P(A,B|C). I'm just not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "There should be a way to get $P(A|C)$ directly"? In general, if you know $P(A,B|C)$, you can use the relation $P(A|C) = \sum_{\mathcal{B}} P(A,B|C)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't establish a relationship between event A and event C from the given information. The dependency and independency between event A and event C might occur. You can utilize Venn diagram to illustrate both cases. The given information indicates $\text{A} \!\cap\!\text{B}  \neq \varnothing$ and $\text{B} \!\cap\!\text{C} \neq \varnothing$. Now your goal is to check $\text{A} \!\cap\!\text{C}  \stackrel{?}{=} \varnothing$ from the given information. Using Venn diagram, the dependency and independency between event A and event C might occur. For the later case, see the below picture

[image]

Now is it possible to show the former case? Yes, it is. See the below picture,

[image]

Notice that for both cases, $\text{A} \!\cap\!\text{B}  \neq \varnothing$ and $\text{B} \!\cap\!\text{C} \neq \varnothing$ hold.